# Rename instead of delete resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there any way to avoid resource deletion when reorganizing/renaming resources? Example: when I first implemented CloudFront Terraform it was an independent sub directory in my project, later I switched to using it as a module in. my root Terraform config but this caused Terraform to want to delete the old CloudFront distribution and create a new one:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:
    - aws_cloudfront_distribution.main_site_distribution
    + module.cloudfront.aws_cloudfront_distribution.main_site_distribution
```

Is there any way to force Terraform to rename the resource instead?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Unfortunately Terraform doesn't know that you've renamed/moved the resource around but you could tell it where the resource should be stored in the state by using [`terraform state mv`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html).

In your case if you ran:

```
terraform state mv aws_cloudfront_distribution.main_site_distribution module.cloudfront.aws_cloudfront_distribution.main_site_distribution
```

and then run another plan you should see no changes (or only the changes to the resource you have made as well as the move).

Answer (score 1):

Terraform v1.1+ now has a `moved {from... to...}` block which can be used for these sort of refactoring.

I'd strongly recommend using `moved {}` over changing state via the terraform cli.

Per your example this would fix the delete and create:

```
moved {
  from = aws_cloudfront_distribution.main_site_distribution
  to   = module.cloudfront.aws_cloudfront_distribution.main_site_distribution
}
```

[Terraform refactoring documentation has been updated](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring).