# Renaming s3 bucket in Terraform (but not S3) causes create then destroy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I want to refactor my Terraform scripts a bit.

Before:

```js
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "abc" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
  acl    = "private"
  region = "${var.aws_region}"

  tags = {
    Name = "My bucket"
  }

  versioning {
    enabled = true
    mfa_delete = false
  }
}
```

After:

```js
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "def" {
  bucket = "my-bucket"
  acl    = "private"
  region = "${var.aws_region}"

  tags = {
    Name = "My bucket"
  }

  versioning {
    enabled = true
    mfa_delete = false
  }
}
```

As you can see, only the name *in Terraform* has changed (`abc` -> `def`).

However, this causes a create / destroy of the bucket in `terraform plan`.

I expected Terraform recognize the buckets as the same (they have the same attributes, including `bucket`).

**Questions:**

- Why is this?
- Is there a way to refactor Terraform scripts without destroying infrastructure?

Comment: because of the resource state is not changed, you just changed the code only. So you have to follow the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename instead of delete resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49112142/rename-instead-of-delete-resource)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`terraform state mv`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html), to reflect this change in the state.

In you case, this would be

```
terraform state mv aws_s3_bucket.abc aws_s3_bucket.def
```

From my own experience, this works well and I recommend doing it instead of working with bad names.

Terraform does not recognize such changes, no :-)